# Why does file not found error occur while using python as database in html

Tags: pycharm, filenotfounderror

I am writing a simple html code with just two inputs and try to save it with local server made with python http module in pycharm IDLE, server started but while inputting data and saving it with local server (text file) i am constantly getting file not found error what can I do for this

I was trying to creating local server with python module , everything connected but the file(the entered input) is not saved